# How to stop execution while waiting for user input in a Modal View

Tags: cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

I have a Navigaton Controller displaying a TableView and a toolbar with a button.
If the user presses the button a modal view is displayed with several buttons. On pressing one of those buttons a new set of data is loaded and the tableView is reloaded.

Under a certain condition when a new set of data is reloaded I need to show a modal view to alert the user of some situation.

This is the code I original write to show the alert to the user:

```
- (void) selectEventosListMVCButtonPressed:(NSInteger)button    
{
    switch (button) {        
    .
    .
    .
    .
    case 3:
        // eventos favoritos

        // Load Favourites Events
        // This is the new data to load
        if (!self.eventosFavourites) {
            [self loadEventos:kURLEventosCopyFavourites];
        }
        // Empty the container
        [self.eventosListsContainer removeAllObjects];
        // Load Favourites Eventos
        [self.eventosListsContainer addObject:self.eventosFavourites];
        // Reload the view
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        // Load Expired Events
        // If there are some eventosExpired then show alert to user
        if (!self.eventosExpired) {
            [self loadEventos:kURLEventosCopyExpired];
        }
        if (self.eventosExpired) {
            // There are expired eventes
            // Load a modal view to inform the user
            ExpiredEventosMVC *expiredView = [[ExpiredEventosMVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExpiredEventosMVC" bundle:0];
            expiredView.delegate = self;
            expiredView.eventos = self.eventosExpired;
            [self presentModalViewController:expiredView animated:YES];
            [expiredView release];
        }
        break;
}
[self.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.modalViewController release];
}
```

But the modal view never shows.
For this to work I should wait after the ExpiredEventosMVC modal view  is displayed to the user click the OK button in that view to dismiss it and continue the flow, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're presenting the modal controller with this line of code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:expiredView animated:YES];
```

And then immediately dismissing it two lines later:

```
[self.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Your code should dismiss the controller *after* the user has pressed one of its buttons, not before. To do this, configure the buttons to send action messages to your controller, and call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` from there.

By the way, naming the variable in which you're storing a view controller `expiredView` is likely to lead to confusion. Consider `expiredController`, `expiredViewController`, or `expiredVC`. (But not `expiredMVC` -- that's not such a good idea either. MVC is an acronym for Model-View-Controller -- a design pattern, not a class.)